# バックアップデータをリストアしたウェブサイトでPHPエラー：Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in ... function.php on line 242

Tags: php, cakephp, wordpress

レンタルサーバーでPHPのエラーで困っています。

バックアップデータをリストアしたらブラウザに以下の１行しか表示されなくなってしまいました。

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/public_html/sysadmin/common/function.php on line 242

該当ファイル該当行周辺の抜粋です。

```
236 function field_name_list()
237 {
238   global $dbh,$mainname,$db_tbl;
239
240   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($db_tbl);$i++)
241   {
242     global $$db_tbl[$i];
243     $in.=$db_tbl[$i];
244     if($db_tbl[($i+1)]!=""){ $in.=","; }
245   }
246
247   return $in;
248 }
```

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 19:30:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

レンタルサーバーの自動バックアップからデータをリストアしたら、掲題のエラーが出てページが表示されません。ドキュメントルートにPHPでウェブサイトを作って、ドキュメントルート/blogにWordPressをインストールしてます。

バックアップデータは１週間前のもの。その時はウェブサイトは動作してたそうです。
確認したことは以下の通り。

1. ウェブサーバー領域を初期化
2. バックアップデータをリストア
3. トップページへアクセスすると掲題のメッセージが一行だけ表示されます。
4. WordPressの管理画面にはログインできます（`http://example.com/blog/wp-admin`)
5. WordPressの管理画面から「サイトを表示」を選ぶと同じエラーが発生
6. WordPressの管理画面からWordPress本体、プラグインを最新化しても結果変わらず
7. WordPressのDEBUGオン。結果は以下へ。
8. メンテ画面を作って置く

初質問になります。どなたか知見のある方、お願いいたします。

---

**WordPressのDEBUGオン時の画面表示と該当するコード抜粋**

> Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /var/www/public_html/blog/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208

```
206                 function nplurals_and_expression_from_header( $header ) {
207                         if ( preg_match( '/^\s*nplurals\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*;\s+plural\s*=\s*(.+)        $/', $header, $matches ) ) {
208                                 $nplurals   = (int) $matches[1];
209                                 $expression = trim( $matches[2] );
210                                 return array( $nplurals, $expression );
211                         } else {
212                                 return array( 2, 'n != 1' );
213                         }
214                 }
```

> Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /var/www/public_html/blog/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-23-related-posts-plugin/init.php on line 440

```
439         if (!empty($tags)) {
440                 $post_tags = '[' . implode(', ', array_map(create_function('$v', 'return "\        '" . urlencode(substr($v, strpos($v, \'_\') + 1)) . "\'";'), $tags)) . ']';
441         } else {
442                 $post_tags = '[]';
443         }
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: meta_noindex in /var/www/public_html/libs/meta.php on line 73

```
73 <?php if($meta_noindex==1 and $blog!=1){ ?>
74 <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
75 <?php }elseif($blog!=1){ ?>
76 <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
77 <?php } ?>
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: mainname in /var/www/public_html/sysadmin/common/tbl_inc.php on line 6

```
4 switch ($mainname)
5 {
6   case 'member':
7     $db_tbl=array("member_id","name","nickname","sex_cd","mail","password","facebook_user_i        d","facebook_url","role_cd","is_toll","toll_datetime","is_wish_toll","is_temp","zip","pref_        id","address1","address2","tel","url","birth","office_name","is_tel_public","is_mail_magazi        ne","know_cd","login_fail","is_login_lock","is_search","fee_standard_cd","fee_minimum_cd","        fee_skillful_cd","plan_target_cd_list","signature_move_cd_list","skillful_structure_cd_list        ","appeal","img_title_list","freeword","view","is_publish","publish_datetime","ins_datetime        ","ins_login_id","upd_datetime","upd_login_id","del_datetime","del_login_id","img_flg");
8   break;
```

Comment: 提示いただいたコードを動かしていないのでなんともいえないのですが、該当ファイルの242行目の「global $$db_tbl[$i];」を「global $db_tbl[$i];」に変更すれば、提示されたエラーは出なくなるような気がします。ドル記号が2つついているので、エラーになっているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうざいます。ドル記号が2つから１つに変更してテストしましたが結果は同じでした。

Comment: PHP5.xと7.xで異なる部分ですね。 https://www.php.net/manual/ja/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

コマンドではPHP5.4だと表示されていましたが、レンタルサーバー（Xserver）のサーバーパネルでPHPバージョンを確認したら、PHP7.2でした。

ドメインを初期化した時にデフォルトPHPバージョンは７.２でした。そこにPHP5.4で開発したソースコードをリストアした為に、エラーや警告メッセージが表示されていたようです。

サーバーパネルでPHPバージョンを５.４.１６にして、バックアップしたデータを再びリストアすることで解決しました。